# Double port forwarding kubernetes + docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, port-forwarding, psql, kubectl

Summary:

I have a docker container which is running kubectl port-forward, forwarding the port (5432) of a postgres service running as a k8s service to a local port (2223).
In the Dockerfile, I have exposed the relevant port 2223. Then I ran the container by publishing the said port (`-p 2223:2223`)

Now when I am trying to access the postgres through `psql -h localhost -p 2223`, I am getting the following error:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

However, when I do `docker exec -ti` to the said container and run the above psql command, I am able to connect to postgres.

Dockerfile CMD:

```
EXPOSE 2223
CMD ["bash", "-c", "kubectl -n namespace_test port-forward service/postgres-11-2 2223:5432"]
```

Docker Run command:

```
docker run -it --name=k8s-conn-12 -p 2223:2223 my_image_name:latest
```

Output of the docker run command:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:2223 -> 5432
```

So the port forwarding is successful, and I am able to connect to the postgres instance from inside the docker container. What I am not able to do is to connect from outside the container with the exposed and published port

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are two possible solutions that may help in your case:

1. You can add the `--address` argument to the `kubectl port-forward` command with the IP address of the container running this command. By default, `kubectl` binds only to localhost and therefore it does not work as you expect (see: [Kubectl Reference Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward)).
2. All newly-started containers connect to a default `bridge` network unless otherwise specified. To solve your problem, you can use the `host` network instead of the `bridge` network. As may be found in the [Docker host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) documentation:

> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated.

I will briefly describe both solutions to show you how it works.

---

First, I prepared `postgres`:

```
# kubectl get pod,svc
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/postgres   1/1     Running   0          155m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/postgres     ClusterIP   10.110.151.73   <none>        5432/TCP   2s
```

*Ad 1.*

This approach is very similar to yours, I just added the `--address` argument:
**NOTE:** I used a container with `kubectl` already installed. I just want you to pay attention to the `kubectl port-forward --address $(hostname -i),localhost service/postgres 2223:5432` command.

```
root@kworker:~# docker run -it --name=k8s-conn-12 -p 2223:2223 -v /config:/config mattjcontainerregistry/forward:latest bash
root@31b05af956ab:/# kubectl port-forward --address $(hostname -i),localhost service/postgres 2223:5432 --kubeconfig=config
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:2223 -> 5432
Forwarding from 172.17.0.2:2223 -> 5432
```

From another terminal tab we can check if it works:

```
root@kworker:~# docker exec -it k8s-conn-12 bash
root@31b05af956ab:/# psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 2223
psql (12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), server 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1))
WARNING: psql major version 12, server major version 13.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

In addition, we can do the same from the host machine (from outside the container with the exposed and published port):

```
root@kworker:~# psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 2223
psql (11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1), server 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1))
WARNING: psql major version 11, server major version 13.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

*Ad 2.*

This approach requires the use of a **host** network:

> host: For standalone containers, remove network isolation between the container and the Docker host, and use the host’s networking directly.

**NOTE:** I just want you to pay attention to the `--network=host` option (I used the same container as before):

```
root@kworker:~# docker run -it --name=k8s-conn-12 --network=host  -v /config:/config mattjcontainerregistry/forward:latest bash
root@kworker:/# kubectl port-forward service/postgres 2223:5432 --kubeconfig=config
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:2223 -> 5432
Forwarding from [::1]:2223 -> 5432
```

Again, we can check if it works as expected from outside the container:

```
root@kworker:~# psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 2223
psql (11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1), server 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1))
WARNING: psql major version 11, server major version 13.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

---

Additionally, it's worth considering if you really need a docker container for port forwarding. Perhaps running `kubectl port-forward` in the background would be better (see: [Perform kubectl port-forward in background](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/kubectl-port-forward/#Perform_kubectl_port-forward_in_background)).

Comment: Thanks a ton @matt_i expecially for the explanation. Worked like a charm.